# Spring Cloud Config: client doesn't attempt to connect to the config server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I'm trying to create a simple Spring Cloud Config server/client setup and am loosely following the documentation:

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/

I've so far implemented a server that seems to work correctly, i.e. return the correct property values when I call the corresponding endpoint:

```
GET http://localhost:8888/config-client/development

{
  "name": "config-client",
  "profiles": [
    "development"
  ],
  "label": null,
  "version": null,
  "state": null,
  "propertySources": [
    {
      "name": "classpath:/config/config-client-development.properties",
      "source": {
        "user.role": "Developer"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm, however, not having any luck with getting the client to connect to the server. I have done the following:

1. Added the `spring-cloud-starter-config` dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

2. Added a `bootstrap.properties` file:

```
spring.application.name=config-client
spring.profiles.active=development
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
```

But I'm still getting a

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'user.role' in value "${user.role}"
```

when trying to run the client application.

There is nothing in the application log that even looks like the client is attempting to communicate with the configuration server.

Link to a **minimal** GitHub repository that reproduces the issue:
https://github.com/Bragolgirith/spring-cloud-minimal

Steps to reproduce:

1. Build and run the `config-service` application
2. Build and run the `config-client` application

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I will check that

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK, mistery solved.

It seems a new Spring Cloud version was released a week ago (https://spring.io/blog/2020/10/07/spring-cloud-2020-0-0-m4-aka-ilford-is-available) that has a new way to activate the bootstrap process - now it doesn't happen by default, but requires adding an additional dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Although this new version is now the default you get when using the
Spring Initializr, the documentation is still not updated to reflect the changes - they are only briefly mentioned in the release notes.

As an alternative to using the abovementioned `spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap` dependency and a `bootstrap.properties` file, it seems the following is now also possible (and even preferred):

application.properties

```
spring.application.name=config-client
spring.profiles.active=development
spring.config.import=configserver:http://localhost:8888
```

Comment: I doubt if it is possible through application.properties

Comment: I get this error 20:10:34.729 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load config data from 'config-server:http://localhost:8888'
 at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.getReferences(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:128)