# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'some.other.property' in value "${some.other.property}"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config-server

I am new to Spring technology and this issue has been bugging me for hours. My spring cloud config client isn't able to read properties from the config server because I am getting an **IllegalArgumentException**. The config server displays all the properties, but I think there is an issue with the name attribute in the **propertySources list** and my wild guess is that it is the reason why I am getting this issue. I am attaching the source code, error and the output here. Please help me out!!

**Error:**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.1)

2021-01-03 22:52:41.286  INFO 6124 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.ConfigClientAppApplication         : Starting ConfigClientAppApplication using Java 14.0.2 on RahulNair with PID 6124 (C:\Users\nairr\Documents\DB Learnings\Spring Apps\Spring Cloud\config-client-app\target\classes started by nairr in C:\Users\nairr\Documents\DB Learnings\Spring Apps\Spring Cloud\Spring_Cloud_And_Microservices)
2021-01-03 22:52:41.286  INFO 6124 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.ConfigClientAppApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-01-03 22:52:41.467  INFO 6124 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2021-01-03 22:52:41.467  INFO 6124 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2021-01-03 22:52:43.907  INFO 6124 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=ccf80bff-8490-3f1d-990f-4b6383bd7788
2021-01-03 22:52:44.391  INFO 6124 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 6451 (http)
2021-01-03 22:52:44.407  INFO 6124 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-01-03 22:52:44.407  INFO 6124 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.41]
2021-01-03 22:52:44.548  INFO 6124 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-01-03 22:52:44.548  INFO 6124 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3081 ms
2021-01-03 22:52:45.038  INFO 6124 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-01-03 22:52:45.471  INFO 6124 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2021-01-03 22:52:45.647  INFO 6124 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 15 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2021-01-03 22:52:45.723  INFO 6124 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 6451 (http) with context path ''
2021-01-03 22:52:45.833  WARN 6124 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.configClientController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'some.other.property' in value "${some.other.property}"
2021-01-03 22:52:45.836  INFO 6124 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-01-03 22:52:45.853  INFO 6124 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-01-03 22:52:45.877  INFO 6124 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-01-03 22:52:45.908 ERROR 6124 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.configClientController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'some.other.property' in value "${some.other.property}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:405) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1415) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:608) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$1(AbstractBeanFactory.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:381) ~[spring-cloud-context-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.get(GenericScope.java:184) ~[spring-cloud-context-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:371) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1159) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh.RefreshScope.eagerlyInitialize(RefreshScope.java:124) ~[spring-cloud-context-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh.RefreshScope.start(RefreshScope.java:116) ~[spring-cloud-context-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh.RefreshScope.onApplicationEvent(RefreshScope.java:111) ~[spring-cloud-context-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh.RefreshScope.onApplicationEvent(RefreshScope.java:66) ~[spring-cloud-context-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:426) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:383) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:943) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:591) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.example.configclientapp.ConfigClientAppApplication.main(ConfigClientAppApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'some.other.property' in value "${some.other.property}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:178) ~[spring-core-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124) ~[spring-core-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:239) ~[spring-core-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210) ~[spring-core-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:931) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1308) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    ... 33 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

I am getting the following output when I hit the ./{config-client-name}/{client-profile} endpoint of the spring cloud config server. The part where I think there is a problem is highlighted in yellow.

***[Spring Cloud Config Server Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keTQV.png)***

**Following is my config-server code**

**pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>config-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>config-server</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring cloud</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

**application.properties**

```html
spring.application.name=config-server
server.port=8888
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/rahul976451/config-server-props.git
```

**JAVA code**

```java
package com.example.configserver;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.EnableConfigServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class ConfigServerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Following is my config-client code**

**pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>config-client-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>config-client-app</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring cloud</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

**application.properties file**

```
server.port=6451
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

**bootstrap.properties file**

```
spring.application.name=config-client-app
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
eureka.client.server-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

**JAVA CODE**
**main.java**

```java
package com.example.configclientapp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class ConfigClientAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigClientAppApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**ConfigClientAppConfiguration.java**

```java
package com.example.configclientapp;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix ="some") //Going to represent our property that is named some.property
public class ConfigClientAppConfiguration {

    private String property;

    public String getProperty() {
        return property;
    }

    public void setProperty(String property) {
        this.property = property;
    }
}
```

**ConfigClientController.java**

```java
package com.example.configclientapp;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation.RefreshScope;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RefreshScope
public class ConfigClientController {
    @Autowired
    private ConfigClientAppConfiguration properties;

    @Value("${some.other.property}") //from the configuration server's application.properties file
    private String someOtherProperty;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String printConfig(){
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append(properties.getProperty());
        stringBuilder.append(" || ");
        stringBuilder.append(someOtherProperty);
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

Sorry if there is any silly mistake from my end, and please do point it out if there. Thank you!

Comment: Any logs in the config client? There should be logs for reaching out to config server

Comment: Error is occurring while starting up server, so it can be that your target folder is not proper. In that case try `mvn clean install`. Now other thing I think can cause issue is that it is not able to load properties file. In that case, you can use `PropertySource` annotation and then try again. If that too does not work, let me know and we will try to figure it out. Good luck!

Comment: I have the same issue following the couse on Pluralsight

Comment: I think I found the fix. Add "some.other.property=foo" inside application.properties file

Comment: @spencergibb no there are no logs as such. I pasted the logs that are visible when I run the config client in the above problem.

Comment: I don't know if it's related, but I noticed that you're using `spring-cloud-config-client`. Could you try to swap it to `spring-cloud-starter-config` and see what happens?

Comment: @MarcosBarbero I did try that too, but in vain. Please take a note at the value in the name property in the propertysources list, in the image attached. Something is off. the name should come as **https://github.com/rahul976451/config-server-props/config-client-app.properties** but it gets added with some local file system uri. Is that normal? Because if I use gradle the the name property has correct value.

Comment: It's normal behavior. The config-server clones the repo to the local machine and then serves the properties from there.
Do you perhaps have the code for the config-server and config-client available on a public repo?

Comment: If it works in gradle but not maven, maybe you have a corrupt dependency?

Comment: @spencergibb No actually I was missing a spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap dependency and explicit mention of bootstrapping in the client's bootstrap.xml, both of which I have given in my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Take also a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75608178/spring-boot-on-open-liberty-illegalargumentexception-could-not-resolve-place/75622301?noredirect=1#comment133426692_75622301

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the fix myself. Seems that the client bootstrapping doesn't occur automatically in new Spring Cloud release, instead we need to add following dependency and explicitly mention the bootstrapping in bootstrap.xml in the config-client.

**Add the dependency**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And then I just added the following line in bootstrap.xml of my config-client and it worked magically.

```xml
spring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled=true
```

I got this from this link:

[Spring Cloud Config: client doesn't attempt to connect to the config server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64836981/spring-cloud-config-client-doesnt-attempt-to-connect-to-the-config-server):

Thank you so much guys for your help and contribution! Thanks @Bragolgirith for the fix. Hope this helps people and save their time.

Comment: or use the new `spring.config.import=configserver:` in application.properties without bootstrap

Comment: Hi [RAHUL NAIR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11201144/rahul-nair),
You don't need to add **spring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled=true** to the **application.properties**. It's superfluous.
But the 2 dependencies: **spring-cloud-starter-config** and **spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap** are mandatory.

Answer (score 3):

“${some.other.property}” is trying searching for that property in the application.properties file and trying to inject its value in the someOtherProperty variable as expected in this portion of the code:

```
 @Value("${some.other.property}") //from the configuration server's application.properties file
    private String someOtherProperty;
```

Looking at your application.properties file, it is clear that no such entry named some.other.property is defined. There lies the problem, Spring is trying to inject a value not present in such file.

Comment: Yes if I put the property some.other.property in application.properties file, it will work. But the point here was that config client must fetch the property from the config-server which points to the git repository for the properties file. Or please correct me if I have misunderstood the concept. Thank you for the response!!

Comment: @RAHULNAIR  you are correct on understanding, however even I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

add "some.other.property=foo" in application.properties file and also add the following in the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Today is 21st January, 2022 (spring boot version 2.6.3) and config client configuration is done through three settings:

1. Only add **spring-cloud-starter-config** dependency in your pom.xml
2. Set the url for config server in **application.properties**: **spring.config.import**=configserver:http://localhost:8888
3. Set the name of the client in order for it to fetch configuration assigned only to it: spring.application.name=movie-catalog-service

spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap dependency and bootstrap.properties are **not** required.

**NOTE**: spring-cloud.version=2021.0.0